# invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::vector<int>')

Tags: c++, templates, vector, ostream

I have the following problem. I´m just trying to output a vector but it says "invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and
      'const std::vector')"

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>




template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T = int>
class Number
{

  private:
   std::vector<T> v[N]; // Vector que contendrá el numero desglozado
   void toBase(int valor);

 public:
   Number(int valor); // Constructor
   Number <B,N,T> suma(const Number<B,N,T>& sumando) const;
   std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os)const;
 };


template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
Number<B,N,T>::Number(int valor)
{
  toBase(valor);
  std::cout << write() << std::endl;
}



template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
void Number<B,N,T>::toBase(int valor)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int aux = valor % B;
    v[i].push_back(aux);
  }
}



template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T>
std::ostream& Number<B,N,T>::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    os << v[i] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I thought the problem was that i was trying to output the vector with a simple for loop. So i tried to output it with an ostream but i have the same error. So the ostream its ok i think. 
Just the outputting vector is the problem and i dont know why.
Any ideas? Thanks you!

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "number.hpp"


int main() {

Number<2,10> N1(100);
Number<2,10> N2(200);

}
```

Comment: `v` is an *array* of vectors, for starters.

Comment: `v` is an *array* of vectors, for starters. Vectors don't come with an `operator<<()` ...

Comment: You also have a problem with `std::cout << write()` and with the fact that `write` is a non-void function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: It's the same array/vector confusion again. If you really think you need an array of vectors then you are going to have to write two loops, an outer loop to go through the array and an inner loop to go through the vector.

Comment: I know what a vector is. I dont get your point.

Comment: @Michalistico I know you know what a vector is, it's the way you are combining it with an array that is very strange and IMHO almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @Michalistico I see you've dropped the pointer you had in your previous code. That is an improvement.

Comment: You got me there.. I came from programming in Javascript, this is a bit strange for me :/ Soz for my dumbs questions/posts

Answer (score 1):

It seems you confused with braces.

```
std::vector<T> v[N];
```

You declaration above declares the array of vectors. I think you want to declare a vector with 4 elements/digits. In this case you have to use other braces:

```
std::vector<T> v{N};
```

Comment: I dont understand that. Are you saying that, for example, if i want to create a vector of int numbers, with N size, the " std::vector<T> v[N]; " is wrong? I have to use braces instead like " std::vector<T> v{N}; " ?

Comment: @Michalistico YES ITS WRONG

Comment: Yes, you are understand it correctly. As a member of a class you should use {N}. But as a local variable of a function you can also use (N).

Comment: @Michalistico A vector of ints it just this `std::vector<int> v;`. That's a vector of size zero and you can add ints using `push_back`. If you want a vector that starts at size N then that would be `std::vector<int> v{N};` or `std::vector<int> v(N);`. Then you wouldn't need to use `push_back`.

Comment: I understand.. SO lost in C++. Thank you guys, soz for the dumb post :/

Comment: If you want getting a fixed size vector then std::array is more preferable.

Comment: @S.M. That's the other confusion. Code above uses `push_back` but then what's the point of the template parameter `N`. I think `N` is not needed and a vector of inital size zero is required but I'm sure the OP will sort it out.

Comment: Why cant i use push_back or push when i already know the size?

Comment: Okey. Thank you!